# pandas concat of dataframes with unequal length and set multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two problems, preferably solving both at once if possible...

I have 3 dataframes, `df1`, `df2`, `df3` with the same number of columns but different number of rows. I want to concat them based on column and then create multiindex on the columns, with `['df1', 'df2', 'df3']`.

I tried `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])`.

I get the following error:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (348, 4686), indices imply (348, 4626)`

I did a mock test with **equal** length and I was able to get the result I want. How can I do this with unequal length dataframes?

```
df_list = []
for i in range(3):
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5)))
df = pd.concat(df_list,axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post dataframes as pictures

Comment: let me know whats the best way to display the dataframe

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error, or I might be failing to understand the issue. I constructed dataframes with dimensions (5,5), ..., (8,5) and the same call to `pd.concat` returned a proper `dataframe`, with rows filled with `NaN` for the lower dim dataframes.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the issue lies not in the `pd.concat` call, but on the indexes of your `df1`, `df2` and `df3`. Try either calling `reset_index` on each `dataframe`, or using `ignore_index=True` in your `pd.concat` call.

Comment: reset_index() does work... but why? In my actual dataframes, the index is a bunch of strings that may or may not overlap between each of the dataframes.

Comment: actually... reset_index() did not work. It did not join the column that I wanted, but instead just stuck the dataframes together by range(row_num)

Comment: @A1122 I tried concating three dataframes with unequal length but same columns, it worked with your piece of code, only you will see NaN for the rows which are not available in either of the dataframes